# Como buscar una palabra o varias en una frase ? JAVA

Tags: java, android

Tengo un filter en un adaptador para filtrar una lista de productos

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(searchBox.getText().toString());
        }
```

El filtro se hace en un `TextWatcher`, sin embargo no funciona cuando quiero buscar por ejemplo **broca de 1 1/2** ; no muestra coincidencias cuando agrego el **1 1/2**

Cabe mencionar que si funciona cuando busco un numero como 234 si un item lo contiene lo filtra

Comment: Hay una mejor opción que usar TextWatcher, usando un array de palabras y una clase que sirve para esto, en el sitio me parece que existe una pregunta similar.

Comment: lo que sucede es que en cada cambio de letra necesito que se vaya filtrando la lista

Comment: Esto se puede realizar con un "auto completador" de hecho existen en el SDK clases para ayudar a esto.

Comment: como los puedo buscar?

Comment: Me parece que el algoritmo de Longest Common Subsequence te puede servir. Esta respueta (en javascript) implementa el algoritmo. Es lo que usan los programas tipo diff para encontrar las similitudes y diferencias entre dos textos. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82714/detecci%c3%b3n-de-errores-de-escritura-falla-al-presionar-la-tecla-retroceso-backspa/84211#84211

Answer (score 3):

Mira ver si este ejemplo te ayuda a solucionar el problema de los caracteres que no se incluyen en la búsqueda...

En el **MainActivity** o donde implementes el **TextWatcher** prueba

```
EditText etSearch;
BaseAdapterFilterable adapter;

etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Listview name of the class
            Listview.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

En tu adaptador pon esta clase para usar el metodo getfilter

```
@Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();
        // if constraint is empty return the original names
        if(constraint.length() == 0 ){
            Result.values = Original_Names;
            Result.count = Original_Names.size();
            return Result;
        }

        ArrayList<String> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<String>();
        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        String filterableString;

        for(int i = 0; i<Original_Names.size(); i++){
            filterableString = Original_Names.get(i);
            if(filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)){
                Filtered_Names.add(filterableString);
            }
        }
        Result.values = Filtered_Names;
        Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();

        return Result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Names = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Tambien en tu adaptador retorna una instancia desde la clase filter_here

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}
```

> Nota:  En el constructor de tu adaptador inicializa el objeto from filter class "filter_here filter = new filter_here();" sobreescribe el metodo getfilter y retorna filter

Answer (score -6):

La función .indexOf() nos devuelve la posición, mediante un número entero, de una cadena o un carácter dentro de una cadena de texto nada. En el caso de que el carácter o la cadena no exista se devuelve un -1.

La búsqueda se realizará desde el principio de la cadena. Si queremos que sea desde una posición concreta podemos utilizar el parámetro fromIndex.

```
public class ContadorDePalabras {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Texto
    String sTexto = "palabra o palabra y palabra";
    // Texto que vamos a buscar
    String sTextoBuscado = "palabra";
    // Contador de ocurrencias 
    int contador = 0;

    while (sTexto.indexOf(sTextoBuscado) > -1) {
      sTexto = sTexto.substring(sTexto.indexOf(
        sTextoBuscado)+sTextoBuscado.length(),sTexto.length());
      contador++; 
    }

    System.out.println (contador);

}

}
```

Comment: El OP no requiere solo buscar cuantas veces se encuentra una palabra en una cadena, te sugiero revisar la pregunta nuevamente, saludos.